# How to split a repository for front end / API / Admin access (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, git, bitbucket

How can you take an existing repository, with many branches, and split it so that some (new front end devs) have access to only parts of the code, but retain the history in the main/full repo?

We have a (huge) Laravel project with a few SPA parts, and 3 separate admin sections. It's all currently in one single repo. Assuming I set up an online dev server so that the API is retrieving the right data based on the branch/version they're working on, is it possible to split the repo so that I (and a few others) have access to the full codebase, while others only can clone/push/pull from a sub repo? The sub repo would exclude the admin sections and API. I assume I'll have to completely restructure the project directory, which is fine.

We all work remotely, and I'm aiming to hire a few new people but don't want to give access to the full code base right away.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know if you can. In my experience with Git (or Bitbucket, etc.), all changes to the codebase in its entirety is tracked and visible to anyone with access. I've never seen codebases segmented for access by arbitrary conditions (i.e. new hire vs tenured employee). What's the reasoning behind wanting this? Is there sensitive information in the Repo you don't want visible to new hires? Or if security is an issue, you can always restrict push access to `main`/`master` branch, i.e. only allow changes via an approved branch, PR and merge etc. It's an interesting question though!

Comment: @TimLewis The repo is clean, no api secrets or anything like that. It’s a popular site and we’re often the target of attacks. Boss wants to make sure that the code wouldn’t get out helping someone probe for vulnerabilities. There are a couple people I’d like to make a job offer to, but hesitant to hand over the full code base on day 1.

Comment: Gotcha; that's an interesting problem to have! I've never even considered the possibility that someone would get themselves hired as a means of stealing code, but I haven't worked for any extremely large-scale operations. Hopefully the submodules approach works out for you! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. You can use git [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

In this regard you can have the smaller codebase repo in a 'submodule' which lives inside your main larger repo.

Steps you'd need to take:

- Remove the relevant code from the main repo
- Add it to a fresh repo
- Call the following commands from the main repo:

```
git submodule add [URL to smaller repo]
git submodule init
```

Nice article on it [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GitSubmodules/article.html)

Comment: I was looking at submodules and was thinking in the wrong direction dependency wise. I restrict access to the main repo, and grant access to the front end submodule and required routes/controllers. I guess this could work the other direction where I put the admin area in a submodule and restrict access to that.